# Installing Glassfish 3.1 on Ubuntu 10.10 Server

Tags: ubuntu, glassfish

I've used the directions [here](http://nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-301-on-ubuntu) to successfully install Glassfish 3.0.1 on an virtualized (VirtualBox and VMWare) Ubuntu 10.10 Server instance without any real difficulty not resolved by more closely following the directions.  However when I try applying them to Glassfish 3.1, I seem to keep getting stuck at section 6. "Security configuration before first startup".  In particular, there are some differences I noted:

1)  There are two keys in the default keystore.  The 's1as' key is still there, but another named 'glassfish-instance' is also there.  When I saw this, I deleted and recreated them both along with a 'myAlias' key which I was going to use where needed.

2)  When turning the security on it seems like part of the server thinks it's on, but others don't.  For instances:

```
$ /home/glassfish/bin/asadmin set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.admin-listener.security-enabled=true
server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.admin-listener.security-enabled=true
Command set executed successfully.

$ /home/glassfish/bin/asadmin get server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.admin-listener.security-enabled
server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.admin-listener.security-enabled=true
Command get executed successfully.

$ /home/glassfish/bin/asadmin --secure list-jvm-options
It appears that server [localhost:4848] does not accept secure connections. Retry with --secure=false.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Command list-jvm-options failed.

$ /home/glassfish/bin/asadmin --secure=false list-jvm-options
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-client
-Djavax.management.builder.initial=com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AppServerMBeanServerBuilder
-XX: UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/endorsed${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/endorsed
-Djava.security.policy=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/server.policy
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/login.conf
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Xmx512m
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/cacerts.jks
-Djava.ext.dirs=${com.sun.aas.javaRoot}/lib/ext${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.javaRoot}/jre/lib/ext${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.in
stanceRoot}/lib/ext
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/autostart/
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-XX:NewRatio=2
Command list-jvm-options executed successfully.
```

Also the admin console responds only to http (not https) requests. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you were following my tutorial at http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-301-on-ubuntu - right?

in the meanwhile I have added another tutorial for installation of GlassFish 3.1 at http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-31-on-ubuntu

maybe this is what you are looking for. i still have some more ideas/improvements that i plan to add to the new tutorial within the next 2 weeks...

nabi

Comment: Yeah, I'm the same guy who left the comment on your instructions for 3.0.1 and I saw that you updated the instructions.  I haven't had a chance to try it out yet but will do so shortly... may even try it with Ubuntu Server 11.04.  Will let you know how it goes later this week. -&&

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks for researching this.

Comment: Works with 11.04, too.

Comment: thanks - that's great to hear! please let me know if you have some improvements which i could add to the tutorial. also feel free to leave a post on my page...